# Parsing a batch file in MinGW

Tags: windows, batch-file, mingw

Hi I have a curly one.

I am trying to download a webdriver for Selenium via batch file in a Ming64W command window.

This command works in Ming64:

```
curl -vs https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/releases/latest/ |grep -i "v0.16.1"|cut -d\" -f2
```

But when I execute it in a batch file I am having trouble understanding the order in which the command line parsers will execute.

This code:

```
#GetFF.bat
curl -vs https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/releases/latest/ |grep -i "v0.16.1"|cut -d^^^" -f2
```

doesn't work because the delimiter for `cut` must be a single character and `\"` is not a valid batch file delimiter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it turns out that this is all a bad idea. The problem is that the parser that handles DOS batch files strips tokens out as it goes but on the other hand bash does not. So the parsers end up in a deadlock against each other. Easy to fix. Redo the UNIX commands with a little help from xmllint and bsdtar. Code is:
`curl -vs https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com |xmllint --format -|grep -i "$win32"|grep -i "<Key>$forceversion"|cut -d '>' -f2|sort -nrk1|head -1|cut -d '<' -f1|awk '{system("curl -o '$win32' https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/"$1)}'|bsdtar -xf - -C chromedriver-x86.exe`